# Using bodegraph with XeLaTeX in WinEdt does not update bode plot

Tags: xetex, bodegraph

In the simple code given below, the bode plot does not plot with used in `XeLaTeXify`.  I did put in the `--shell-escape -enable-write18` in the `XeLaTeX` console window:

[image]
However, I just get the grid and no plot.

I do see `gnuplot` in the WinEdt path.

Can you tell me if `bodegraph` works with `XeLaTeXify`? If so, can you tell me how to get this code to compile in `XeLaTex` within WinEdt. Thanks!

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
    ref lines/.style={thin, blue!60},
    ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size= 3pt, inner sep=0},
    every node/.style={font=\small},
    bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
    xscale=12/3]
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,yscale=4/80]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-2}{2}{-60}{80}

%% Bode plot (magnitude) for the original system, 4/(s/(1+2s)).
%% Asymptotic line
\BodeAmp[ref lines, red!60]{-1:1.8}{\POAmpAsymp{18}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}
%% Bode plot
\BodeAmp[bode lines, black, name path=Gomagnitude]{-1:1.35}{\POAmp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

%
% Axes label
\node [below=6pt] at (0.5,-60) {Frequency, $\omega$};
\node [rotate=90] at (-2.2,5) {Magnitude, $20\log(|G(\text{j}\omega)|)$};


\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not a XeLaTeX code... you have to add at least a language... try to add \usepackage{polyglossia}       
\setmainlanguage{english}   
\setmainfont{A Font Here}  ... I don't have gnuplot and I don't know what XeLaTeXify is

Comment: If you dont use polyglossia use the command \usepackage[english]{babel}... It works for me, but it can not open a gnuplot file...

Comment: @koleygr, thanks for your solution, XeLaTeXify  - runs Biber and PDFTeXify with with the XeLaTeX engine.  I had to put those commands above `--shell-escape -enable-write18` in the PDFTeXify tab for the code to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Please write it as an answer and chose it as correct for users who will find the same problem....Oooops thought that you was a new user of forum ... lol

Comment: @koleygr, if I do, I do not think that the +50 bounty points will go to you??

Comment: You found the solution... Not me... So you can keep your points :)

Comment: You don't need both (`--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18`) . The options are synonyms. And polyglossia or babel are not required for xelatex, but it is sensible to add one of this package (I would use babel for an english document).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer... I think you have to include polyglossia to have hyphenation and to load the language... At least for Greek it is not optional (may be because of the non-latin characters... but I am not sure... I will check and come back)

Comment: @koleygr Well I am sure. For many languages you can use either polyglossia or babel. Which one is better depends on the language. For english, german, french, greek and a number of other languages I prefer babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from @koleygr pointed me to the solution.  As  `XeLaTeXify` runs `Biber` and `PDFTeXify` with with the `XeLaTeX` engine, by putting in the `--shell-escape` under the `PDFTeXify` tab helps fix the issue.  Building on what @koleygr said, we also need to include

```
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{english} 
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Also, from the comment made by @Ulrike Fischer, we need to only put `--shell-escape` under `PDFTeXify`.  Here is the update to the `PDFTeXify`:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{english} 
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
    ref lines/.style={thin, blue!60},
    ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size= 3pt, inner sep=0},
    every node/.style={font=\small},
    bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
    xscale=12/3]
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,yscale=4/80]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-2}{2}{-60}{80}

%% Bode plot (magnitude) for the original system, 4/(s/(1+2s)).
%% Asymptotic line
\BodeAmp[ref lines, red!60]{-2:1.8}{\POAmpAsymp{18}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}
%% Bode plot
\BodeAmp[bode lines, black, name path=Gomagnitude]{-1:1.35}{\POAmp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

%
% Axes label
\node [below=6pt] at (0.5,-60) {Frequency, $\omega$};
\node [rotate=90] at (-2.2,5) {Magnitude, $20\log(|G(\text{j}\omega)|)$};

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with xelatex. And the avant package won't work correctly either. Use the commands of fontspec to setup the fonts.

Comment: Edited solution with your comment and deleted `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} `

Comment: Nice joe.. I don't use much add ons... I prefer pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX ... but I am happy you found the solution... I use the package [utf8]{inputenc} but this is for Greek +1 for posting a detailed answer... Somebody will need it and all we are learning new stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

### A little background: what is `PDFTexify`?

`PDFTexify` **is a WinEdt command** and not the name of a compiler. It mimics the behaviour of MiKTeX's `texify.exe` accessory by running a LaTeX compiler, whose default value is `pdflatex.exe` as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

together with other programs that take care of bibliographies, indexes, glossaries, etc., to get a fully compiled document (if you install the needed plugins, it also compiles Asymptote figures, PythonTeX code, etc.).

The default engine for compiling bibliographies is `bibtex.exe` as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

The name of the compiler is stored in an environmental variable called `PDFLATEX` while the name of the other compilers are stored into WinEdt variables like `BibTeX-Executable` for the bibliography compiler.

---

### A little background: what is `XeLaTexify`

`XeLaTexify` **is also a WinEdt command**, available when you install the plug-in [LaTeXify](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/LaTeXify.html), **which** (excerpt from the plug-in documentation):

> XeLaTeXify (**runs Biber and PDFTeXify with XeLaTeX engine**)
>
> Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+E</kbd>

and this is its definition in the `MainMenu.ini` configuration script:

```
ITEM="XeLaTeXify"
  CAPTION="&XeLaTeXify"
  IMAGE="TeXXeLaTeXify"
  SAVE_INPUT=1
  MACRO=`Assign("Old-BibTeX-Executable","%$('BibTeX-Executable');");`+
        `Assign("BibTeX-Executable","biber.exe");`+
        `Assign("OLD-PDFLATEX","%@('PDFLATEX');");`+
        `SetEnvVar("PDFLATEX","xelatex.exe");`+
        `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFTeXify.edt');`+
        `Assign("BibTeX-Executable","%$('Old-BibTeX-Executable');");`+
        `Release("Old-BibTeX-Executable");`+
        `SetEnvVar("PDFLATEX","%$('OLD-PDFLATEX');");`+
        `Release("OLD-PDFLATEX");`
  SHORTCUT="49221::Ctrl+Alt+E"
  REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
```

*What does this mean?*

The `XeLaTeXify` command is a wrapper around the WinEdt command `PDFTeXify` which sets the environmental variable `PDFLATEX` to the value `xelatex.exe` and the inner variable `BibTeX-Executable` to the value `biber.exe` *before* calling the command `PDFTeXify` itself (these values are restored after the execution).

In other words, when you click on the button `XeLaTeXify` you are running

> - xelatex
> - biber
> - (eventually) other compilers like makeindex, makeglossaries, etc.
> - xelatex (again if needed)
> - biber (again if needed)
> - xelatex (again if needed)

The whole process is handled by the `PDFTeXify` macro, which is called by `XeLaTeXify`.

---

### Conclusions and answer to the question

Being `XeLaTeXify` a wrapper around `PDFTeXify`, this means that if you want to modify its behavior like adding command-line switches, as in your case, you have to modify the properties of the `PDFTeXify` command in the Execution Modes dialog.

[image]